# In Python 2.6, How Might You Pass a List Object to a Method Which Expects A List of Arguments?

Tags: python, list, arguments

I have a list full of various bits of information that I would like to pass to several strings for inclusion via the new string `format` method.  As a toy example, let us define

`thelist = ['a', 'b', 'c']`

I would like to do a print statement like `print '{0} {2}'.format(thelist)` and `print '{1} {2}'.format(thelist)`

When I run this, I receive the message `IndexError: tuple index out of range`; when mucking about, it clearly takes the whole list as a single object.  I would, of course, rather it translate `thelist` to `'a', 'b', 'c'`.

I tried using a tuple and received the same error.

What on Earth is this particular technique called?  If I knew the name, I could have searched for it.  "Expand" is clearly not it.  "Explode" doesn't yield anything useful.

My actual use is much longer and more tedious than the toy example.

Answer (score 10):

`.format(*thelist)`

It's part of the calling syntax in Python. I don't know the name either, and I'm not convinced it has one. See the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists).

It doesn't just work on lists, though, it works for any iterable object.

Comment: I think it's referred to as "unpacking".

Comment: @Devin: There is much similarity between binding some names via `=` operator and binding function parameters names on function call.

Comment: You are correct. Which also means I linked to the wrong section (off by one). Corrected.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: They're diverging significantly. Many of the similarities are being dropped-- for instance, in 3.0, one cannot def f((a, b), c). One can still do (a, b), c = [(1,2), 3] .

Comment: @Devin: you haven't followed your own link? just in a next section comment says "call with arguments unpacked from a list".

Comment: @SilentGhost: Yes. I didn't read titles, I just looked for "*args".

Answer (score 2):

```
'{0} {2}'.format(*thelist)
```

[docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#index-757)